# Pygame restart?

Tags: python, user-controls, while-loop, pygame

I have my game running in a while True loop and I would like to be able to ask the user to "Play again?" I already have the code for a rect to pop up with the text but I need a way for the user to click on the rect or hit y for yes and the code run its self again.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your main program loop, make a new `event.key` if statement for whichever key you want the player to press to restart the game, then call `main()` inside the if statement. This will reset everything back to square 1.

In my example below, I detect if the user has died and pressed the <kbd>R</kbd> key, then restart `main()`.

```
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.go_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.go_right()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.jump()
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

            if event.key == pygame.K_r and not player.alive():
                main()
```

Further down in the main loop I display some text asking the player to press the R key to respawn.

```
        if not player.alive():
            gameover = font.render("Press R to Respawn", False, (255, 255, 255))
            rect = gameover.get_rect()
            rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
            screen.blit(gameover, rect)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the loop it's own method, call it from a `main()` run, when the game is over and ends, have `main()` ask the user if they want to play again, and if so recall the main loop after setting everything as its default

or

Just have the part that asks again clear and reinitialize all variables as there defaults and let the loop  if the user wants to play again

Answer (score 1):

To tell if the user clicked on the rect, just set a 1 by 1 rect at the mouse position then when they click, check if the rects are colliding. Then, just call the loop again by having it be its own function, like DeadChex said.

Answer (score 1):

Run this function I've written especially. Tweak it to your heart's content. If the player dies (*or whatever happens to make the play again text appear*) you only have to call play_again()

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
bigfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 80)
smallfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 45)

def play_again():
    text = bigfont.render('Play again?', 13, (0, 0, 0))
    textx = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2
    texty = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2
    textx_size = text.get_width()
    texty_size = text.get_height()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), ((textx - 5, texty - 5),
                                               (textx_size + 10, texty_size +
                                                10)))

    screen.blit(text, (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - text.get_width() / 2,
                       SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - text.get_height() / 2))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.flip()
    in_main_menu = True
    while in_main_menu:
        clock.tick(50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                in_main_menu = False
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                x, y = event.pos
                if x >= textx - 5 and x <= textx + textx_size + 5:
                    if y >= texty - 5 and y <= texty + texty_size + 5:
                        in_main_menu = False
                        break

play_again()

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
```

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this:
at the end of the code put something like this to ask the user if he wants to play:

```
play_again = 1

while play_again:
    play_again = int(raw_input("Play again? 0=No, 1=Yes"))
    if play_again:
        main()
    else:
        break
        pygame.quit()
```

In my example i put a `True` at the end of the `while` loop of my `main()` function, so that the `main()` returns allways `True`, which makes it possible inside of the `play_again` loop to repeate the game if the user input has been `1` and exit if `0`.